# Google App engine python2.7 Boto AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPSConnection'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ubuntu-18.04, boto, google-cloud-sdk

I am recently working on a project that uses Google App Engine running on python2.7 on Ubuntu18.04. Files need to be uploaded to AWS S3, so we are using boto for this. However running the code outside the app works but when running it inside GAE it gives me the following error:

```
 ERROR    2021-05-12 03:54:54,582 webapp2.py:1552] 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPSConnection'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/depotter/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk-282.0.0-linux-x86_64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/home/depotter/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk-282.0.0-linux-x86_64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/home/depotter/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk-282.0.0-linux-x86_64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/home/depotter/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk-282.0.0-linux-x86_64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/home/depotter/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk-282.0.0-linux-x86_64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/home/depotter/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk-282.0.0-linux-x86_64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/depotter/projects/mwcentral/server/./online_ordering/ctg/menu.py", line 204, in post
    self.send_menu(company_key, store_id, timestamp)
  File "/home/depotter/projects/mwcentral/server/./online_ordering/ctg/menu.py", line 257, in send_menu
    result = self.upload_menu(menu, company_key_id, store_id)
  File "/home/depotter/projects/mwcentral/server/./online_ordering/ctg/menu.py", line 295, in upload_menu
    key.set_contents_from_string(file)
  File "/home/depotter/projects/mwcentral/lib/boto/s3/key.py", line 1442, in set_contents_from_string
    encrypt_key=encrypt_key)
  File "/home/depotter/projects/mwcentral/lib/boto/s3/key.py", line 1309, in set_contents_from_file
    chunked_transfer=chunked_transfer, size=size)
  File "/home/depotter/projects/mwcentral/lib/boto/s3/key.py", line 762, in send_file
    chunked_transfer=chunked_transfer, size=size)
  File "/home/depotter/projects/mwcentral/lib/boto/s3/key.py", line 963, in _send_file_internal
    query_args=query_args
  File "/home/depotter/projects/mwcentral/lib/boto/s3/connection.py", line 671, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler
  File "/home/depotter/projects/mwcentral/lib/boto/connection.py", line 1071, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler)
  File "/home/depotter/projects/mwcentral/lib/boto/connection.py", line 913, in _mexe
    self.is_secure)
  File "/home/depotter/projects/mwcentral/lib/boto/connection.py", line 705, in get_http_connection
    return self.new_http_connection(host, port, is_secure)
INFO     2021-05-12 03:54:54,590 module.py:865] remote-ordering: "POST /api/ctg/tasks/menu/send HTTP/1.1" 500 3685
WARNING  2021-05-12 03:54:54,590 taskqueue_stub.py:2149] Task task2 failed to execute. This task will retry in 40.000 seconds
  File "/home/depotter/projects/mwcentral/lib/boto/connection.py", line 755, in new_http_connection
    connection = http_client.HTTPSConnection(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPSConnection'
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTPSConnection module missing in Python 2.6 on CentOS 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877072/httpsconnection-module-missing-in-python-2-6-on-centos-5-2)

Comment: It's close but I am afraid not, GAE runs the packages from it's own folder 'lib'. Nevertheless followed the steps to compile with ssl again and got ">>>hasattr(socket,"ssl")>>>True". So I believe with this my socket supports ssl.

Comment: I know this is a bit of a silly question, probably, but may we see the contents of your requirements file? It seems like the App Engine instance may be using a different version or missing something that your code is expecting and it'd be good to just get that out of the way and discard it.

Comment: Sure, at the moment in my requirements.txt i have boto==2.49.0 
In my app.yalm  i have libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"

- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"

- name: pycrypto
  version: "2.6"

- name: ssl
  version: latest

- name: setuptools
  version: "36.6.0"

Comment: @ManAlone I apologize for the week-late response, I apparently forgot to follow the posts I commented on a lot that week and didn't notice your message. I have however, thankfully, looked into this a little more and it would seem like GAE asks that you have the SSL library as part of the [app.yaml libraries section](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sockets/ssl_support), it seems that GAE might include the library but not compile with it unless it's in the app.yaml, or at least that's what the documentation seems to imply on a first read.

Comment: @fabc Hey thanks for coming back on this! That's seems like some great possible solution! I am going to try it later. Currently we could solve it temporary changing is_secure = True in boto.

Comment: Does the answer provided by @fabc works in your case? If it does, I will do a community wiki to help other users.